# Is there a statistical measure of clustering in a point pattern process that scales dependent on clustering?

Tags: statistics

I am trying to find a statistical measure of clustering for point pattern processes that scales according to degree of clustering and it appears to be a question that is largely unaddressed in the field. For raster or polygon type grids for example we can use Moran 1 autocorrelation (global) or LISA (local) to measure a degree of correlation. However, for point patterns there is no equivalent that can give a single value of clustering. There are distance methods, such as a chi square test, that tell us whether there is clustering, but measures such as K, L and G functions give values across a range of distances. I am an amateur at statistics but after searching for days I cannot find a test that will simply tell me the degree of clustering across the landscape. I have attached two plots below to demonstrate the sort of landscapes that I am working with.

[image]

[image]

All I want to show is the degree of clustering for each landscape, as a single value. Is this even possible mathematically?

Many thanks.

Comment: I'm also interested in knowing this answer. Ripley's K function seems to estimate clustering across all possible distances, but it is computationally expensive. I would like defining a distance spectrum where to test clustering.